# Get fields from intermediate table on Sequelize belongsToMany

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I have an **M:N** relationship between **Team** and **Player**. For this relationship I created a model **TeamPlayer** and a `belongsToMany` association:

```
const TeamPlayer = Sequelize('team_player', {
  tp_code : [...] // PK
  id_team : [...] // FK to Team,
  id_player : [...] // FK to Player,
  position : Sequelize.STRING,
});

Team.Players = Team.belongsToMany(Player, {
  through : TeamPlayer,
  foreignKey : id_player
});
```

This works fine as I'm able to retrieve a list of players for each team but the `position` field is not being included on the generated SQL. The only fields being selected are `tp_code` and `id_team`.

Documentation doesn't help very much on understanding how to setup `belongsToMany` relationship properly but I wonder if there is any configuration for getting intermediate table fields or if I would need to manually define a join statement.